# Accessing Docker Services from Host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a simple web app with a `docker-compose.yml` configuration like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

I can access the database service within the web app container with `postgres://db:5432` because both containers share networking.

I'd like to access the database service from my host machine using `postgres://db:5432`. How do I map the `db:5432` host from the container to `db:5432` on my local host machine? I've tried adding `127.0.0.1:5432  db:5432` to my `/etc/hosts` file which does not seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/etc/hosts` file is simply a way to statically resolve names when no DNS server is present or resolved. It can't map port addresses.
Ref: https://serverfault.com/questions/54357/can-i-specify-a-port-in-an-entry-in-my-etc-hosts-on-os-x

It will work if you do,

```sh
127.0.0.1       db
```

Remove the port and it will work.

Also, you can directly access Postgres with `localhost: 5432` from host machine.

Comment: Exactly what I was after

Comment: Glad it helped :)